# How can I get a button's outline to fill the span in which it is contained?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The blue in the following image is the button, and the green represents the `span` in which it is enclosed.

[image]

When I click, I want the button's color change and click effect to fill up the entire `span`. Right now, it only fills up the blue area.

I have tried `button-block` on the button, as well as `width:100%`. This is all taking place in my nav bar, by the way.

**EDIT:**
Code:

```html
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><img src="assets/mylogo.png" class="logo-small"></li>

      <div class="input-group" style="width:80%;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" style="height: 60px; border: 0; outline:none; box-shadow: none;" placeholder="Search here" onsubmit="do()"/>
        <span type="button" class="input-group-addon" id="shade" style="background-color: transparent; border-color: white;">
          <button class="btn search-button" type="submit" onclick="this.blur();" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; width:100%;">
            <i class="fa fa-2x fa-search"></i>
         </button>
       </span>
    </div>
   </ul>
```

Comment: It seems like your <span> has a padding set. Remove the padding from your span and the button should fill in the entire span.

Comment: @GuillermoCarone Does not look like there's any padding. It's all within a `<div class="input-group">...`

Comment: if you can provide the URL were this is happening I can take a better look. It's tough with just a screenshot...

Comment: Can you pls show some html?

Comment: There's no link yet, but the code is in the post now @RaJeshRiJo

Comment: span type button ?? is it valid???

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't place block elements inside inline elements (span). It's against HTML specification. And I hope you are using css in separate file and that's just example ;)

And for your problem, if you insist to leave this like that, did you try something with overlay or important? My first idea was that, the problem should be in your font class (fa fa-2x fa-search).

Comment: Modifying the button itself, replacing it with text, etc. did not work.